# android build server with crashlytics

Tags: android, gradle, crashlytics

I have a android build server which uses APKTool to decompile and then assemble apps again. So the same code base is used and some settings and name, package page, icon and other things are changed for each app and are assembled again. This is something that is already implemented.

I wanted to integrate crashlytics into this. But the problem is crashlytics is available as a gradle plugin and they submit to their API when you build it from source. I decompiled the class files and figured out the API call and called it manually. This works fine. But just wanted to see if we can install gradle and whatever tools required on the build server and directly execute the plugin task alone?

For iOS they have provided a tool so that solves it elegantly:

http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/370383-beta-distribution-with-ios-build-servers